# Google Calendar API - Push notifications not working

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm using the Google Calendar API and am trying to receive push notifications when a calendar event is triggered https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push

I think everything is setup correctly...

```
gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
  calendarId: 'primary',
  resource: {
    id: uuid,
    type: 'web_hook',
    address: window.location.href,
  },
}, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('response:', response);
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log('res:', res);
});
```

But I guess not. I get a 200 response when I call the above code

```
{
 "kind": "api#channel",
 "id": "...",
 "resourceId": "...",
 "resourceUri": "https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json&maxResults=250&alt=json",
 "expiration": "1554203159000"
}
```

I believe I should also be receiving a sync message, but I am not (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#sync)

To test things I am modifying an event within the calendar itself (changing the title, date, deleting, etc), and I expect something to happen in my browser, but nothing.

I'm not familiar with Push notifications in general, so not exactly sure what to expect.

I'm already authenticated and displaying events as per https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

What am I missing? Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your request looks fine.   It looks like the watch has been set up properly.  Your only going to get a response when something is changed

Comment: The docs state `After creating a new notification channel to watch a resource, the Google Calendar API sends a sync message to indicate that notifications are starting.` Of which I'm not :/

Comment: @DaImTo what do you mean be 'change'? I'm getting notifications come through when I have the calendar open, but nothing here

Comment: You are setting up a push notification on an event.  If that event changes the api will notify you at the location you have specified.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm watching the 'primary' calendar. So am I correct in assuming that when an event sends a notification i.e. 10 mins before, then I my code should call `console.log('response:', response);`?

Comment: Thats NOT push notifications.

Comment: I'm at the same point right now, I get the expected response after doing a POST to the watch endpoint but the webhook I specified with the adress is not receiving anything after editing an event from my calendar

Comment: oh its working now, I did a mistake in my php script to log if any request was coming in so I didnt see that there was a request. Now I'm logging the request headers and saw that google did requests when I changed something in my calendar

Comment: @ducci hey I am stuck as well . can you help?? i dont see anything nothing really happens.... my webhook url is not triggering

Comment: @ReyYoung can you be more precise? what step are you stuck at? did you create a  POST request to create a watch request and got a successful response out of this? Then in the next step I would check for the logs or build a script which reads incoming requests and their headers since google will send you a request with a header X-Goog-Resource-State: sync so you know the watcher is active. when you create a script to log incoming requests, your webhook url should point to that script

Comment: @ducci Ok before this ... is there anyway I can get the gogle username looks like google plus service not working

Comment: @ReyYoung what do you mean? why would you need a google username and what does this even mean? Also I just did this with google calendars which are public available

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are miss understanding exactly what push notifications is.

There are two primary ways to track when a resource has changed. You can poll that resource often and check for any changes in the resource.

For example Your application could run every five minutes and make a request to Google asking to have the event returned to you.  When that event is returned you will then check if there are any changes in the event created by the user.  This method of checking for changes is very time consuming and requires resources to constantly poll the server looking for changes.  A better way of doing it is using [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push)

[Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) notify your application when a change has been made.

> This document describes how to use push notifications that inform your application when a **resource changes**.

Its set up by enabling a watch

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https:/examle.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

This tells Googles servers that you would like to be notified when ever someone makes a change to the event. This sets up a web hook to https:/examle.com/notifications which will be notified as soon as there is a change to the event.

Name of the event, date time are normally changes i dont think you will get a push notification if someone else is added to the event.

**What this is not**

The server is NOT going to send you a message 10 minutes before the event is due.  Thats user notification and something completely different and not part of the Google Calendar api.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info and clarification @DalmTo. So I'm still not getting any notifications when I change an event in my calendar though. If name and date changes don't trigger a push notification, then what does?